# -->Input String was not in correct format

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, shopping-cart

```
if (!blnMatch)
 {
     DataRow shoppingCartDataRow;

     shoppingCartDataRow = shoppingCartDataTable.NewRow();
     shoppingCartDataRow["ProductID"] = int.Parse(productid1);
     shoppingCartDataRow["Quantity"] = 1;
     shoppingCartDataRow["ProductName"] = ProductName;
     shoppingCartDataRow["ProductPrice"] = decimal.Parse(ProductPrice); 
     //-->Input String was not in correct format..Why is the input string for price not in correct format?

     shoppingCartDataTable.Rows.Add(shoppingCartDataRow);

 }
```

Comment: What is the value of `ProductPrice`?

Comment: Is ProductPrice a string? Try stepping through the code and checking what the value of ProductPrice is before decimal.Parse is executed.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the value of `ProductPrice` cannot be converted into a decimal (for example, if there are letters). Check if the value of `ProductPrice` would be a sensible value for a decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing an error because ProductPrice cannot be converted to a Decimal, meaning it has an incorrect format.  Open up your debugger and make sure you have a valid string to parse.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx

You could add some validation by using [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx)

```
decimal convertedProductPrice;
if(decimal.TryParse(ProductPrice, out convertedProductPrice))
  shoppingCartDataRow["ProductPrice"] = convertedProductPrice;
else
  shoppingCartDataRow["ProductPrice"] = 0;//assign a default value on failure
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method to check this something like below.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static decimal ToCurrency(this object value)
    {
        const NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands
                                   | NumberStyles.AllowParentheses | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign
                                   | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol;

        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
        decimal tempValue;
        decimal.TryParse(value as string, style, culture, out tempValue);
        return tempValue;
    }
}


shoppingCartDataRow["ProductPrice"] = ProductPrice.ToCurrency();
```